# Unknown Word on SCSS mixin function using Stylelint

Tags: webpack, mixins, scss-mixins, stylelint

I'm working on a webpack boilerplate, and I've been trying to set up a `px to rem` conversion function using scss mixins. I'm using `stylelint` to check for errors in this project too.

I keep getting the following errors, and I'd like some help with fixing this please.

### Terminal

```
When linting something other than CSS, you should install an appropriate syntax, 
e.g."postcss-scss", and use the "customSyntax" option

13:19  ✖  Unknown word  CssSyntaxError
```

My code for the mixin is as follows:

### Mixin

```
$html-font-size: 16px;

@function stripUnit($value) {
    @return $value / ($value * 0 + 1);
}

@function ptpx($ptValue) {
    @return stripUnit($ptValue * 1.333);
}

@function rem($pxValue, $unit:'px') {
    @if $unit == 'pt' {
        @return #{ptpx($pxValue) / stripUnit($html-font-size)}rem;
    } @else {
        @return #{$pxValue / stripUnit($html-font-size)}rem;
    }
}
```

The following is my config for stylelint:

### Config

```
module.exports = {
    rules: {
      "at-rule-no-unknown": true,
      "block-no-empty": true,
      "color-no-invalid-hex": true,
      "comment-no-empty": true,
      "declaration-block-no-duplicate-properties": [
        true,
        {
          ignore: ["consecutive-duplicates-with-different-values"]
        }
      ],
      "declaration-block-no-shorthand-property-overrides": true,
      "font-family-no-duplicate-names": true,
      "font-family-no-missing-generic-family-keyword": true,
      "function-calc-no-unspaced-operator": true,
      "function-linear-gradient-no-nonstandard-direction": true,
      "keyframe-declaration-no-important": true,
      "media-feature-name-no-unknown": true,
      "no-descending-specificity": true,
      "no-duplicate-at-import-rules": true,
      "no-duplicate-selectors": true,
      "no-empty-source": true,
      "no-extra-semicolons": true,
      "property-no-unknown": true,
      "selector-pseudo-class-no-unknown": true,
      "selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown": true,
      "selector-type-no-unknown": true,
      "string-no-newline": true,
      "unit-no-unknown": true
    }
  };
```

I'm quite lost with this, could someone please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As the warning in the console states, you'll need to use [a custom syntax](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/usage/options#customsyntax) to lint SCSS as it's not CSS but another language:

> When linting something other than CSS, you should install an appropriate syntax, e.g."postcss-scss", and use the "customSyntax" option

Stylelint's [getting started guide](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started) [recommends](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started#linting-everything-else) extending a shared config that includes and configures the appropriate custom syntax for you.

You should replace your existing configuration with:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard-scss"
}
```

If needed, you can turn off any rules that you don't want to enforce right now using `null`, like so:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard-scss"
  "rules": {
    "color-function-notation": null
  }
}
```